# Angular RXJS HTTPClient not catching errors HttpErrorResponses

Tags: angular, typescript, error-handling, rxjs, observable

Angular 12, I am trying to get a set of unit tests running where they will catch errors coming in the http response, but when the tests run the error is passed in the response body rather than as an error.

Spec.ts file

```
it('Test post method failure', () => {
      const expected: HttpErrorResponse = new HttpErrorResponse({
        error: 'Bad Request',
        status: 400,
        statusText: 'Bad Request'
      });
      service.post({ urlIdentifier: 'test', endpoint: '123' }).subscribe({
        next: res => {
          // This is being run
          console.log(res)
        },
        error: error => {
          // This is not run.
          expect(error.status).toBeCloseTo(expected.status);
          expect(error.statusText).toEqual(expected.error);
        }}

      );
```

Method being tested

```
export class HttpService {
  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {};
  post<T>({ urlIdentifier, endpoint, body }: HttpMethodsArguments): Observable<T> {
    const url: string = this.getBaseUrl(urlIdentifier) + endpoint;
    return this.http.post<T>(url, body, {
      headers: this.getHttpHeaders()
    }).pipe(
        catchError(err => {
          return throwError(err);
        })
      );
  }
```

LOG from res object: HttpErrorResponse(headers:..., status:400, statusText: "Bad Request" ...)
The expected outcome I want is coming through just in the res object in the test instead of as an error.
It's probably something small that I am missing but I can't solve this.

Comment: can you try remove the pipe on the HttpService where you rethrow the error or at least add a console.log there as well to see if the response of that that may cause the issue. Cause it looks correct just skimming over your code.

Comment: `catchError` is only invoked when the source Observable emits an `error` notification. In you case `this.http.post()` emits an error only when the request fails.

Comment: Do you have any for how to throw an error when this.http.post receives an err? (I'll look into it myself, just figured I'd ask.

Comment: Resolved By adding a new pipe that threw the error.

Answer (score 0):

Melvin's comment was correct. An Error was not being thrown so Catch Error was not activating.
I Added a pipe to throw the error in the case of an HttpErrorResponse.

```
export class HttpService {
  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {};
  post<T>({ urlIdentifier, endpoint, body }: HttpMethodsArguments): Observable<T> {
    const url: string = this.getBaseUrl(urlIdentifier) + endpoint;
    return this.http.post<T>(url, body, {
      headers: this.getHttpHeaders()
    }).pipe(
      map(x => {
        if (x instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
          throw x;
        }
        return x;
        })
      )
      .pipe(
        catchError(err => {
          return throwError(err);
        })
      );
  }
```